# How to recover accidently deleted files from RedHat file server

Tags: linux, data-recovery, redhat-enterprise-linux

one of my friend accidently deleted all files (jpg and pdf) from file server by using `rm -rf` command .is there is a way to recover those files with actual file names? i.e. we tried following solutions.

1. testdisk - recovered few files only (with actual file name)
2. photorec - recovered lots of files with useless .txt files (without actual file names)
3. foremost - recoverd pdfs and jpgs without file names

Comment: Restore from your backups.

Comment: thanks for the reply @DavidPostill, there is no backup system. is any way to resolve above matter?

Comment: Professional data recovery services, assuming that you have access to the hardware. It's going to be expensive and results are not guaranteed to be satisfactory. Also, shut down the server _now_ to prevent overwriting the file.

Comment: @gronostaj thanks for the immediate response.